# Json schema validation for date_time not working

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My json schema has the following structure

v0.json

```
"order_datetime": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "The date and time when the order was placed",
                "format": "date_time",
                "examples": [
                    "2021-02-16T13:30:27.816Z"
                ]
            }
```

and the input json has this data

```
"order_datetime": "2021"
```

and this is my schema validator but the validation is successful even though the data is in wrong format

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class OrderJsonSchemaValidator {

public boolean validate(String message) throws JsonProcessingException {

    Schema schema;
    String schemaName = "v0.json";
    try {
        schema = loadSchema(schemaName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Property file " + schemaName + " not found in the classpath in resources messages directory");
    }
    try{
        schema.validate(new JSONObject(message));
        return true;
    }catch (ValidationException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.getCausingExceptions().stream()
         .map(ValidationException::getMessage)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
return false;

}

public Schema loadSchema(String schemaPath) throws IOException {

    Schema schema;
    try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaPath)) {
        JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
        schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
    }
    return schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which implementation you're using, but by default, `format` doesn't DO any validation. In `draft-07` and previous, support for `format` is optional. In draft `2019-09` and above, it is by default an annotation only.

If you want `format` to do semantic validation, you need to check the implementations documentation for support. If they don't list support, file an issue. If you can't file an issue, you could delve into the code.

For JSON Schema draft 2019-09 and above, if you want your schemas to require the use of `format` interoperably, you would need to create a new dialect which specifies the appropriate vocabulary is required.

Comment: I am using "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema"

Comment: Great! What implementation/library though?

Comment: I fixed the issue by re aligning the json schema. I had initially placed required fields before the properties. Just moved the required[] after the properties{}

Comment: OK. I've voted to close this issue as "cause by a typo" and the fix is unrealted to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's `"format": "date-time"`, not `"format": "date_time"`.